# Water heater switch wiring

Tags: switches, switching

I have a switch for a water heater. The electric kind that heats instantly overhead as you take a shower. I am an electric engineering student and I am very curious. This switch has six terminals yet it controls one heater. Anyone who has an idea how this is so and how the wiring diagram would look. The switch  has a red light that is on when it is heating. But two of the terminals are separate from the rest and on both sides they end up where the screws to the patrice box are. Hence I they must be for earthing. Can anyone help please?

Photo of the item in question:

[image]

Comment: Pictures? Model number? Manufactured by?

Comment: I could send a photo of it. I just don't know where to send

Comment: Here is a photo. https://postimg.org/image/dlqfd84e7/

Comment: Already you got it from above comments, allow me to add weight in your question. Is it a must you earth the switch? coz there is a place I feed instant shower earth directly without taking earth wire to switch

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the picture live supply, switched live, neutral supply, switched neutral, two earth connections.

If you do not know what you are doing with this go out and find yourself a competent electrician. You are putting yourself and anyone else who might use it at serious risk.

Comment: Thanks.  I was just curious. I am not going to try wire my shower. I am not a big fan of electric shock

Answer (score 0):

There's two inputs: neutral and hot/live/phase.  Two outputs: switched neutral, switched hot/live/phase.  The two outside ones are earth terminals.

It's pretty obvious that the outer ones are earths, as they are connected to the metalwork around the holes through which the mounting screws go.

For which of the four regular terminals are which, look closely at the markings.  Your photo isn't good enough to see them.  Normally, you'd want the lamp to be on the output.